# Why do Saber and Rin sound disappointed when they see inside Shiro's shed?

Tags: fate-stay-night

In the anime (and also in the visual novel when you make the correct choice), Shiro walks out and overhears Rin and Saber talking. They sound disappointed (maybe even angry) about a discovery they make in the shed Shiro practices in when he does reinforcement on stuff.

Is this in relation to his Unlimited Blade Works Reality Marble and how he has been unknowingly been doing something very wrong when he uses Reinforcement/Projection? Or, is there something else in that shed that Kiritsugu left, and never told Shiro about (like the Crest on the floor which activated when summoning Saber)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tohsaka is probably disappointed because the shed is like Shirou's workshop. Tohsaka is a professional magus; her workshop probably has magical items and books and scrolls, but Shirou has broken junk.

Maybe, it's the same for Saber (but we do not know if Saber knows what a workshop should be like).